# Simulate a general positive lookbehind for VBA regex

Tags: regex, vba, excel, regex-lookarounds

There are a plethora of questions about lookbehinds in VBA. The problem is that, while there are positive and negative lookaheads, VBA [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575282/regex-positive-lookbehind-issue-with-excel-vba) [lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150552/lookbehind-on-regex-for-vba) at all.

Most of the questions people have asked seek to solve a very specific problem of extracting strings from text and the Stack Overflow community has been [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419234/is-this-regex-valid-for-vb/39419877#39419877) [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220224/how-to-simulate-lookbehind-in-vba-regex) in providing [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091194/workaround-for-the-lack-of-lookbehind) for these particular cases. My question is, could you write a function in VB that simulates positive lookbehind by accepting Regex patterns as arguments and doing some kind of find-replace in the resulting string to only return the desired match group while omitting a (required but not captured) prefix?

Comment: Your answer is just another, usual, workaround based on capturing mechanism. It can be written even simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function accepts three arguments in order to satisfy this problem: a string to be matched, the regex pattern of a non-capturable prefix, and the regex pattern of the subsequent capture group.

```
Function LookBehindRegex(ByVal inputText As String, nonCaptureRegex As String, _
   captureRegex As String)

    'Non capturing lookbehind to retrieve reference preceded by a regex group

    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim intermediate As String
    Dim nonCaptureText As String

    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    'First set the capture pattern to both regex groups, to capture the whole text
    regEx.Pattern = "(" & nonCaptureRegex & ")" & "(" & captureRegex & ")"
    'Store that
    intermediate = regEx.Execute(inputText)(0)
    'Next, set the pattern to only capture the non-capture regex
    regEx.Pattern = nonCaptureRegex
    'Store the non-capturable text from the intermediate result
    nonCaptureText = regEx.Execute(intermediate)(0)
    'Finally remove the non-capture text from the intermediate result
    LookBehindRegex = Replace(intermediate, nonCaptureText, "")

End Function
```

*Limitations:* This will only simulate positive lookbehind. The relevant Regular Expressions module must be added as a reference to the VB project.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this give the same result as your answer, with less work?  (Of course, it needs error checking added to it.)

```
Function LookBehindRegex( _
    ByVal inputText As String, nonCaptureRegex As String, _
    captureRegex As String) As String

    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim mac As MatchCollection

    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Pattern = "(" & nonCaptureRegex & ")(" & captureRegex & ")"

    Set mac = regEx.Execute(inputText)
    If mac.Count > 0 Then _
        LookBehindRegex = mac(0).SubMatches(1)

End Function
```