# Regex to extract 3 digit number in an excel function

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need to extract a 3-digit number from text strings in an excel sheet.
I've written my custom function to return a substring based on a pattern, that's fine, it works. It's the pattern that's beating me.
So, examples could include:

- Lorem ipsum dolor cc123 sit amet
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet cc 123
- Lorem ipsum c 123, dolor sit amet

I'm no expert in regex, but usually I'd use **(?<=\D)\d{3}\b** That works with all the tests I've tried but VBA doesn't seem to support (?<=x). Using just \D\d{3}\b and trimming the leading char works, but offends my senses.

I'm using the standard VBscript Regular Expressions 5.5 library.

The practical background to this is that I have a large worksheet that has a comments field on each line. Policy has been that users include their cost centre somewhere in this field. It can appear anywhere in the field, it's always a three-digit number, it is always followed by a word boundary and it is always preceded by a non-number char.

Comment: Excel (VB) doesn't support [positive lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150552/lookbehind-on-regex-for-vba). There's a wee function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662112/simulate-a-general-positive-lookbehind-for-vba-regex) that simulates the functionality in VB.

Comment: BTW, I know there could be lots of exception cases - I'll deal with them. I also know that I could approach this through string manipulation - I just have a tried and trusted regex function and I'd like to use that if possible

Comment: @neophlegm Yes... that looks like it would work. I'll have a play

Comment: A pure-regex workaround could be to write something like this and then only return the first capture group: `\D(\d{3}\b)`

Answer (score 0):

you can go for a backreference solution:

```
\D(\d{3})\b
```

if you are interested only in the 3 digits, you could use the regex described here-over and reuse the first capturing group `\1` (might be `$1` in VB)

Comment: Sadly back refs aren't supported in vba

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is to use : `\D(\d{3})\b`  like in

```
Dim myRegExp, ResultString, myMatches, myMatch As Match
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "\D(\d{3})\b"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(SubjectString)
If myMatches.Count >= 1 Then
    Set myMatch = myMatches(0)
    If myMatch.SubMatches.Count >= 1 Then
        ResultString = myMatch.SubMatches(1-1)
    Else
        ResultString = ""
    End If
Else
    ResultString = ""
End If
```